# get data file from input text jquery

Tags: jquery, html, file, input

How to get data like this:

```
data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJeHp69MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9DYXR…AKdHJhaWxlcgo8PC9TaXplIDE4Ci9Sb290IDEgMCBSPj4Kc3RhcnR4cmVmCjg4MzEzCiUlRU9G
```

from input file

```js
$('#file').change(function(e) {
  var file = $('#file')[0].files;
  for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
    console.log(file[i].name)
    console.log(file[i].type)
    console.log(file[i].size)
  }



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" multiple="">
```

I got the sample like

```
function readURL(input) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.result)
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input);
}
```

I need to get it from on change of input file because i want to put it in the href of an anchor like

`<a class="image" href=' + e.target.result + '><img style="width:150px; height:150px;" u="image" src=' + e.target.result + '></a>`

so that my code looks like

```
$('#file').change(function(e) {
    var file = $('#file')[0].files;
    for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
        $('body').append('<a class="image" href=' + e.target.result + '><img style="width:150px; height:150px;" u="image" src=' + e.target.result + '></a>')
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to append it in `reader.onload` handler and calling `readURL()` from `for` loop. See e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/L5w7fb7j/

Comment: do i need to put return?like return e.target.result? @A.Wolff

Comment: See jsFiddle, but you cannot return from an ansyc method, the onload event. You could use a deferred object but that's quite useless here

Comment: @A.Wolff can you write it as answer i will accept it.. I didnt know it should be like that. Also i didnt know that filereader is async. to reduce un answered question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is adding anchor *once* you get the data file(s) available. The easiest way it to append these elements from reader onload event. See e.g:

```
function readURL(input) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
         // here data is available, you can append it
         $('body').append('<a class="image" href=' + e.target.result + '><img style="width:150px; height:150px;" u="image" src=' + e.target.result + '></a>')
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input);
}

$('#file').change(function(e) {

    var files = $('#file')[0].files;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
         readURL(files[i]);       
    }
});
```